# unable to display .doc from server

Tags: ios, webview, webserver, mamp, doc

I'm trying to load documents into my app for display and this works if they're stored locally but not from the server. I'm testing with MAMP. Here's my viewDidLoad method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *myUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8888/FilesForApp/Docs/MS.doc"];
    NSURLRequest *myRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myUrl];
    [_webView loadRequest:myRequest];
}
```

Can anyone point tell me if there's something missing from this?

-EDIT-
Forgot to add, it doesn't crash, just shows a plain, white display.

Comment: Try putting a URL method (like http://) at the start of your string.  Check the URL and Request for whether they're valid objects.

Comment: Thanks - I've added http://.
How would I go about checking validity of URL & Request?

Comment: Check that they aren't nil when you create them.  Also, it would be good to have a UIWebViewDelegate so that you can track errors from the actual load.  (And check that _webView isn't nil while you're at it.)

Comment: Something like:
if (myUrl == nil) {
        NSLog(@"invalid URL");
    } ?

Comment: Sure...or even just put a breakpoint in there and see what the different variables are set to.

Comment: OK, thanks for your help. I think I'm getting somewhere; both seem to be valid if I connect to an external server but I'm getting invalid URL if I try to connect to localhost.

Comment: In that case, I revert to my UIWebViewDelegate suggestion.  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure you can access that doc through your web browser(make sure the doc exists).
2. Try to add the http:// prefix.
3. Don't forget to add _webView as subView to your view.
4. Don't forget to set the _webView's frame.